# How to apply bootstrap to existing rails file generated through scaffold?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sass, less

through railscasts, I found http://railscasts.com/episodes/328-twitter-bootstrap-basics that with the

```
gem 'less-rails' (this is the gem https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails)
```

I can use

```
rails g bootstrap:themed scaffold-name -f
```

which applies bootstap to various classes like table, buttons etc. This is amazing timesaver but I am not able to find this for SASS as I am using SASS for my rails app (I am using this gem https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass)

IS there any way to apply bootstap to existing scaffold code as me doing this manually can take lot of time ? OR is there any easy way to put the classes in the .erb files ?

Thanks

Comment: If the code is generated through scaffold and not changed, you can generate it again and you will geht what you are looking for.